# DB2 : Restoring Database Warning Message SQL2563W

Tags: db2

While restoring one of the CLM application data's from Database, I got this warning message,

> "SQL2563W The Restore process has completed successfully. However one or more table spaces from the backup were not restored."

Any Solution...

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: Code is already mentioned "SQL2563W". Which code you are expecting from My side? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This typically means that Db2 was not able to acquire the containers that belong to the table space in question. You can also get it for a table space restore that lists a tablepsace that doesn't exist in the database.

There should be more info in db2diag.log.